# JMeter freezes when attempted to upload image from iPhone application

Tags: iphone, jmeter

JMeter freezes when attempted to **upload an image** from **iPhone application** for performance testing via **proxy** ?

```
number of user  : 1 
Ramp Up Period  : 1
Loop Count      : 1
```

Answer (score 1):

My expectation is that JMeter isn't able to find the image locally hence fails to capture the request. Try to copy the image, you're trying to upload from iphone to JMeter's "bin" folder (see [Bug 48479](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48479) for details).

Another possible reason could be missing JMeter's self-signed certificate in case of application using HTTPS to communicate with the server. In that case you will need to install `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` certificate to the iphone (just send it by email and open the email on the iphone)

Alternative workaround for both above situations is capturing the request via [Mobile Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420545-BlazeMeter-Recorder-Mobile-Recorder-) service, however you will still need to copy the image to JMeter's "bin" folder in order to properly replay it.

Comment: Thank you Dimitri for this answer, i tried with the first solution you gave 1. I did copied the image i am trying to upload from phone into Jmeters bin folder and still the jmeter is freezing ..though the image upload request is taken by the jmeter but its still freezing . 2.I also did installed the ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt and i also tried this https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-test-image-upload-functionality-jmeter but still the jmeter is in freeze state.. once again : I am using Jmeter 3.0 , in mac OS X El Capiton 10.11.4 (15E65)  & Iphone Iphone 6 ,9.3.1.